# How to Intialize the Binding Properties in the Fragment to Make Two Way Data Binding Work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-databinding, mobile-application

So I'm doing a project and I'm completely lost. I have seen how to do data binding with TextViews but I am being asked to do it with EditText Views with Two Way Data Binding. I got up to here so far with it.

The XML File.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="myShoe"
            type="com.udacity.shoestore.product.Shoe" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_detail_view"
            style="@style/title_style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:text="@string/add_shoe_title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/shoe_name"
            style="@style/login_style"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/shoe_name_string"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="@={myShoe.name}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_detail_view" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/shoe_size"
            style="@style/login_style"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/size_string"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@={myShoe.size}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shoe_name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/company_name"
            style="@style/login_style"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/company_string"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@={myShoe.company}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shoe_size" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/shoe_description"
            style="@style/login_style"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/description_string"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@={myShoe.description}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/company_name" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="@string/cancel_string"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/savee_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/savee_button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/savee_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="@string/save_string"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shoe_description" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I was told to implement it to a fragment and it should work. But I'm not sure how. Here's the fragment

```
class ShoeDetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: ActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        val binding: FragmentShoeDetailsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_shoe_details,
            container, false
        )



        //initializing the button and clearing the views once canceled
        binding.cancelButton.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
            v.findNavController().navigateUp()

            binding.shoeName.text.clear()
            binding.shoeSize.text.clear()
            binding.companyName.text.clear()
            binding.shoeDescription.text.clear()

        }
        //initializing the button and saving the info to transfer to the shoeList
        binding.saveeButton.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
            v.findNavController().navigateUp()

            val name = shoe_name.text.toString()
            val size = shoe_size.text.toString()
            val brand = company_name.text.toString()
            val details = shoe_description.text.toString()
            viewModel.addShoe(name, size, brand, details)
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

I am open to any ideas to initialize binding properties so i can use it in both the layout and the fragment. Or am I looking at this the wrong way?

P.S. The XML File is being represented in this fragment

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also did this project for my NanoDegree.
Inside my `ViewModel` I created 3 variables for each `EditText`:

- ***MutableLiveData*** - to update the value inside the viewModel
- ***LiveData*** to expose value outside viewModel e.g. in a fragment (*you won't really need this*)
- ***Public Variable*** to monitor value of MutableLiveData and expose this to your xml thus achieving the 2-Way Binding.

Then I and would create a [Shared ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to share data between `ShoeDetailsFragment` and `ShoeListingFragment` .

Inside the SharedViewModel

I created 3 variables for each EditText (this is just the first 2 Edittexts):

```
class MySharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
 private val _name = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val name: LiveData<String>
        get() = _name
    var edShoeName = ""

    private val _size = MutableLiveData<Double>()
    val size: LiveData<Double>
        get() = _size
    var edSize = ""

......}
```

For the xml I did exactly what you have done but used the *3rd variable for the 2-Way Data Binding*:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/shoe_name"
            style="@style/login_style"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/shoe_name_string"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="@={mySharedViewModel.edShoeName}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_detail_view" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/shoe_size"
            style="@style/login_style"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/size_string"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@={mySharedViewModel.edCompany}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shoe_name" />
```

I have seen you have included this line of code on your `ShoeDetailFragment` code:

```
 binding.saveeButton.setOnClickListener { v: View -> ....}
```

In my case I did it inside SharedViewModel instead:

```
fun onSaveButtonClick() {

        //check value entered for size and set it to 0 if blank
        if (edSize == "") {

            edSize = "0"
        }

       

        //update MutableLiveData with values read live from the EditText
        _name.value = edShoeName
        _size.value = edSize.toDouble()
        

        //save shoeObject to the _shoeList MutableLiveData
        _shoeList.value?.add(Shoe(edShoeName, edSize.toDouble(), edCompany, edDescription))

    }
```

Using DataBinding I moved the onClick bit to xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_background"
        android:onClick="@{()->sharedViewModel.onSaveButtonClick()}"
```

[You can also refer to my project](https://github.com/Tonnie-Dev/ShoeStore).

Comment: Appreciate it man. It worked for me. I know there not asking it, but how did you clear the fields after you saved the info? My Cancel button does it but the save button still keeps the info that it saved in the prior Listing.

Comment: Good observation on clearing the fields, this didn't occur to me then but let me see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Appreciate man. And is there a way to connect outside of stackoverflow? I don't know a lot of Android Devs myself.

Comment: Offcourse, I'd be happy to; You can find me on [LinkedIn](www.linkedin.com/in/antony-muchiri) or [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Tonnie_Dev) also don't forget to say Hi to everyone on [Udacity's Students Lounge] (https://hub.udacity.com/rooms/community:hqb2c-3f3e6a86-3abe-4fb0-bc90-d9569897fbf6?contextType=room)